# What's the correct way to use SVG in Opera?

Tags: html, svg, opera

Can anyone tell me how to force Opera opera to render SVG in html?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="142" height="142">
    <rect x="19" y="19" width="104" height="104" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000000"
          style="stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2;" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2"/>
    <rect x="36" y="36" width="70" height="70" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000000"
          style="stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2;" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

This code works fine if file extension is not .html

upd:
I'm trying to put div with svg inside generated by raphael.js in new window. And it doesnt work in Opera.

Comment: When you run it with `.html` extension, is it a valid `.html` document, with `html`, `head`, `body`, etc...?

Comment: Well, if you embed it as an `img` with a `src=[path/imagename].svg`, it doesn't appear to have any problem.

Comment: Yes, with svg file it does work, but image is generating in javascript.

Comment: Sooo... Why does your question only mention markup? Where is the code you're trying to generate?

Comment: How can we possibly help if we don't see the code you're having the problem with?

Comment: I updated the question. I trying to get working simple html example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have SVG in HTML working, the browser must have an HTML5 parser and Opera will have one only since version 12.

If you absolutely have to have SVG right in the HTML code, you need your document to have an xhtml file extension an be a valid xml file (if you are running it from disc), and it also has to be served with `application/xhtml+xml` mime type or another valid xml mime type when sent from a web server.

Comment: That or just create and insert the elements with javascript, which is what e.g Raphaël is doing. Also see http://svgboilerplate.com/ which uses inline svg in html, it contains a script that fixes up the svg inline content for browsers without HTML5 parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SVG in HTML use [SVG in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml).

(Be sure your web server is sending the correct mime type for XHTML.)

Comment: I think the OP may have misspoken (possibly), since it is claimed that XHTML has been used (my own tests were only HTML). However, it's been difficult to get that kind of information.

Comment: So... here is no way just to put markup in div and it would work in Opera?

Comment: Of course, if the correct mime type is sent, it won't work with IE.

Comment: @Marcin That is not true. My web server sends `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` properly for the above file, and it works just fine in IE.

Comment: @globerz Sure. Put content in a div, and use XHTML content-type and markup. A `<div>` is find in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, we've recently released Opera 12 Alpha, which has an HTML5 Parser, and supports inline SVG. It should work in there, and subsequent later versions.