# CSS SVG sprite wrong on IE11 and Opera

Tags: html, css, svg

I will like to get help please with an issue I got in both IE11 and Opera with CSS SVG sprite.
For some reason both of these browsers are showing the SVG in a very wrong way and some times even not at all.

[image: SVG sprite issue on IE and Opera]

Here's my code which works great on Chrome, Safari and Firefox:

```
.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
    background: #eee url('1.svg') no-repeat 0 0;
}

.item.i1 {
    background-position: 5% 40%;
    background-size: 440%;
}

.item.i2 {
    background-position: 43.3% 40%;
    background-size: 417%;
}

.item.i3 {
    background-position: 82.6% 40%;
    background-size: 404%;
}
```

A live jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DBH29/

Am I missing something? if not and my code is fine, and there's no way to fix it, then how can I make a CSS fallback to an image (PNG) or how to detect it with Modernizr please?

Comment: just to add: more precisely, the old good opera 12.x (not newer the webkit one) does behave so.

Comment: "*Here's my code which works great on Chrome, Safari and Opera:*"  Maybe you mean to say that it works great on Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: @dsuess yes I'm talking about the "old" opera not the Opera-next version.

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830158/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-svg-in-opera

Comment: @dsuess that question is unrelated. The core issue is that Opera 12 (Presto) didn't handle background-size and background-position properly for svg images, known bug. Opera Mini will also not display this correctly.

Comment: currently I'm making a fallback using browser detection as: if($.browser.msie || ($.browser.opera && $.browser.version < 15))

Answer (score 0):

possible related to: [SVG in Opera using CSS background-image with scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859995/svg-in-opera-using-css-background-image-with-scaling) , in short to work with Opera 12:

```
"Removing the width and height attributes in the svg"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but unfortunately it didn't worked.